# Error 405 when using "requests" module in Python

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

Update: Issue seems to be with Windows Powershell. Program works in Python IDLE.

So I have installed requests, `urllib3` module properly. But whenever I try to use requests, I get HTTP 405 error. Please check the attached screenshot for my code and the error I get.

- NOTE: I tried attaching images of my code and error but StackOverflow app gave me an error.
- NOTE 2: I have tried GET method too but it doesn't work either, it throws the same HTTP 405 error.

**My code:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

file = requests.post("https://w3schools.com/python/demopage.htm")

soup = BeautifulSoup(file,"lxml");

print(soup.prettify())
```

**Error I get:**

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "requestspractice.py", line
>   1, in 
>       import requests   File "C:\Users\Prasanna\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\requests__init__.py",
>   line 43, in 
>       import urllib3   File "C:\Users\Prasanna\Python1\urllib3.py", line 15, in 
>       resp = urllib.request.urlopen(req)   File "C:\Users\Prasanna\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\urllib\request.py",
>   line 223, in urlopen
>       return opener.open(url, data, timeout)   File "C:\Users\Prasanna\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\urllib\request.py",
>   line 532, in open
>       response = meth(req, response)   File "C:\Users\Prasanna\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\urllib\request.py",
>   line 642, in http_response
>       'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)   File "C:\Users\Prasanna\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\urllib\request.py",
>   line 570, in error
>       return self._call_chain(*args)   File "C:\Users\Prasanna\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\urllib\request.py",
>   line 504, in _call_chain
>       result = func(*args)   File "C:\Users\Prasanna\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\urllib\request.py",
>   line 650, in http_error_default
>       raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp) urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 405: Method Not Allowed

Comment: 405 is not allowed, that might mean you can not `post` to that url, but your code ran fine on my computer on the post part

Comment: I have tried GET method as well but it gives me same error.

Comment: Also you are not using `urllib3`

Comment: Works for me with python-requests, with bot get and post methods.  Can you get the page to load in your browser (on the same computer) ? Are you behind a firewall / proxy / whatever ?

Comment: I haven't activated any firewall, I don't know if Windows 10 have any firewall by default. Page loads correctly in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you want to do is `GET` the page rather than `POST` anything to it.

```
file = requests.get("https://w3schools.com/python/demopage.htm")
```

Comment: I have tried post and get both but I keep getting HTTP 405 error.

Comment: It sure is working on my machine, though. You get same error for `requests.get` too?

Comment: I don't know what's wrong with mine. Whenever I use requests module, I get HTTP 405 error.

Answer (score 0):

Your URL is wrong should be at the end "html", but you're using: "https://w3schools.com/python/demopage.htm"